# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() To-do app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a function that displays tasks of current user

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $user= auth()->user();

    return view('welcome')->with('tasks',$user->tasks);
}
```

This is the code that displays the posts in home view

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
        <td class="table-text">
            <div>{{$task->item}}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Am getting the error above

relationship in user model

```
public function tasks(){
        return $this->HasMany('App\Task');
     }
```

Comment: Show the `tasks()` function in your `app/User.php` model

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you edit your question and add some details on what are $user->tasks?. If it's a relationship can you post the relationship code?

Comment: @girliosalama everything seems fine till now, did you add a foreign key in your tasks database table?

Comment: And even better, please try and `dd($user->tasks)` in   your `test` controller function before the `return` statement and include the result

Comment: FIY it should be `return $this->hasMany('App\Task');` the `HasMany()` function does not exists in laravel 5.

Comment: @dparoli thanks i did not see that mistake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to fix your code lower case h in the hasMany() function

It should be

```
public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
     }
```